# Groovy bean syntax for spring batch job-repository

Tags: groovy, spring-batch

im creating a spring batch (spring-boot) backed by a groovy bean builder. However Im not able to find the right syntax for the following xml construct:

```
<batch:job-repository/>
```

**UPDATED:** beans.groovy

```
beans {

    xmlns([ctx: 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/context', batch: 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch'])
    ctx.'component-scan'('base-package': 'mypackage')
    ctx.'annotation-config'()


  itemReader(MyItemReader) {}

  itemProcessor(MyItemProcessor) {}

  itemWriter(FlatFileItemWriter) { ... }

    batch.job(id: 'job1') {
        batch.step(id: 'step1') {
            batch.tasklet {
                batch.chunk(
                    reader: 'itemReader',
                    writer: 'itemWriter',
                    processor: 'itemProcessor',
                    'commit-interval': 1
                )
            }
        }
    }

  //Option 1: will this work?
  //batch.'job-repository'()

  //Option 2: all job related beans defined individually, because cannot get <batch:job-repository/> in groovy bean syntax
    jobRepository(MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean) {
        transactionManager = ref('transactionManager')
    }

    jobRegistry(MapJobRegistry) { }

    jobLauncher(SimpleJobLauncher) {
        jobRepository = ref('jobRepository')
        taskExecutor = { SyncTaskExecutor executor -> }
    }

    jobExplorer(JobExplorerFactoryBean) {
        dataSource = ref('dataSource')
    }

    jobOperator(SimpleJobOperator) {
        jobLauncher = ref('jobLauncher')
        jobRepository = ref('jobRepository')
        jobRegistry = ref('jobRegistry')
        jobExplorer = ref("jobExplorer")
    }

}
```

I want to use Option 1 technique, if i do that, i get 'beanName must not be empty' error. Instead of I use the beans from Option 2, they appear to be working.

I'm assuming using Option 1, will autoconfigure the jobRepository etc. using other defined beans.

Comment: Can you post what you currently have?

Comment: @MichaelMinella I have updated the post with full configuration. Option 2 works fine, but i was looking for the Option 1 technique syntax. Thanks for help!

Comment: Yes, there is no special Groovy support for that namespace option so option 2 is the only way to go.  We're looking into a Groovy DSL, but it isn't available at this time.

Answer (score 0):

I added a [Jira ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12416) for the namespace option. However when you combine annotations with Groovy DSL you can also solve it, following an example in Spring Boot Batch:

If you have an application class you can annotate it with `@EnableBatchProcessing` to get the requested behaviour:

```groovy
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan

@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class, "appcontext.groovy").run(args)
    }
}
```

However you don't have all configuration in one place.